# Loading Dialog while rotating device

Tags: android

I have an `activity` with in which there is a `async task` that will do some download stuff. AT the time of downlaoding it will show a l`oading dialog`.
My problem is, it worked fine for me when me doing it in only `one orentiaon`. But when i `rotate` at the time of download, it shows `window leaked` and will crash at the
`dialog.cancel`  in my post excute.
From my study on it more i understood it due the `change in the context` when device is `rotated`.
That is when a `device` is `rotated` the `activity` will be `recreated` so the `context` will be `changed`.
*But i have created the dialog with old one and that `wasn't the current context`. So when i cancel it it shows error*
What is the solution for this, any idea frnds.
Me using **`honeycomb`**, me tried but with `fragment` but didnt get a good sample for that. Me now mainly trying that,
*if anyone can give me some links for that it will be 
great*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all: open your dialog using the `showDialog` method ([there are a lot of examples in the official documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html)). If you do so, the activity will take care of dismissing the dialog on destroy, and re-showing it after the activity has been recreated.

Also... if the dialog shows a progress bar (not a wheel), you will want to update the progress of the dialog after orientation changes. In order to do so, I recommend to use the `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance` to return the current state of the dialog and/or the activity itself. Then, you can use `getLastNonConfigurationInstance` to recover that state. Google about those two methods if you want to see examples.

Another thing to keep in mind: if you are updating the state of the dialog an/or any other UI element from the `AsyncTask`, you must be aware that after the activity is recreated, the `AsyncTask` may be pointing to the wrong UI references. In order to handle this, you can create a proxy class (Proxy design pattern) to detach the `AsyncTask` progress notifications from the current UI elements.

Comment: Thanks **Cristian** for you answer. Me used [ProgressDialog](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#ProgressDialog) but for me crashing while rotating.

Comment: What is this **Proxy Design pattern**. Its sound interesting. I don't know anything about it. can you provide some links for that

Comment: Take a look at the source code of the [iosched](http://code.google.com/p/iosched/) app. It has a nice example of how to use `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance`, `getLastNonConfigurationInstance`, as well as the Proxy Design Pattern.